# Python: navigate in Windows Open file dialog window

Tags: python, pyautogui, hotkeys, openfiledialog

The Python software I'm writing interacts with another software that opens an Open File Dialog Windows (and I can't change this)
I need to go to the upper field of the Open Dialog box to type a path, but I can't find a way to do it without mouse.
I didn't manage to do it by using tab combination?
Maybe there is an hotkey combination that I don't know.
Or maybe should I tell Python to detect the Filedialog windows name and find a way to manage it?
I'm using pyautogui.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: the key combination is CTRL + L

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l')
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer as correct (gray check box at the left side). It will indicate to others that solution is found. It is considered polite and motivates others to reply to your other questions.